# navigation menu creating extra unwanted space

Tags: css, html-lists, nav

I've created a nav menu that is unnecessarily adding extra space to the right side of it. When the page is made smaller it adds a scroll bar to the bottom of the page which makes the page uncentered. After some digging in Dreamweaver it looks like the UL element's surrounding box is not centered with the actual navigation menu. It juts off to the right and seems to be causing the problem. How to I get this centered with the nav menu?

I've also included a fiddle below.

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
  
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
  
a {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://svuvn.bandcamp.com/">STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="live.html">LIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
<nav>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmnkxwa8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add in your `nav` the overflow property:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's too much padding in between the menu items. kick that down in the css block:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 30px;  //first parameter is top/bottom, the second parameter is left/right.  kick it down to something like 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

Take out the right:50%; and for margin, use "margin:0 auto;"
the auto will auto-center the nav

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use floats or lefts to align your navbar. Instead try doing this: It makes the navbar centered and no scroll is appearing for small devices. Update your ul and li class to this:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }

  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Furthermore, if you want your navbar to appear in a list form for small devices, simply add this media query for your preferred range:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

 ul li {
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 5px 30px;
        color: white;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        text-align: center;
      }
}
```